# Cannot get orderer logs into debug mode in Hyperleger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I am new to Hyperledger fabric there I have set the orderer logs level into debug like this.

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      #enabled TLS
```

But It is still in the info mode. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check out [this link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging-control.html)

In newer version of Fabric, logging level is controlled by env var `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC`